# What is the mechanism of Python setuptools to determine package path?

Tags: python, setuptools, importerror

I have a package named spider-common.
Another project depends on spider-common, so I have this enviroment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/zjz/spider-common
```

I an run this project like this without any error:

```
python xxxx.py
```

But i have a problem with setuptools. When I run setup.py, some error occured:

```
ImportError: cannot import name SITE_DANGDANG
```

It is because: setuptools probably find an old version of spider-common without SITE_DANGDANG.
But how to make setuptools can find the right package?